# Assembly Program Strange Behavior

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, stdout, masm32

I am attempting to write a small program in MASM that will take a string of user input, subtract four from the ASCII value of each character, then output the new character.

This is mostly successful, except when `StdOut` is called, it prints not only the current modified character, but also the next character.

I've been trying to figure out what is happening for several hours and still don't have a clue.  Here's my code:

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data?
    inputtxt dw 10000 dup(?)
    current  dd           ?

.code
start:
    call main
    exit

main proc
    Invoke StdIn, addr inputtxt, 10000
    xor esi, esi

    processLoop:
        movzx eax, inputtxt[esi]        ; Get the character at index ESI
        sub eax, 4                      ; Subtract 4 from the character's ASCII code
        mov current, eax                ; StdOut can't print a register
        Invoke StdOut, addr current     ; Print the character: the problem lies here.
        inc esi                         ; Increment the loop counter
        cmp byte ptr[inputtxt[esi]], 0  ; If the next character is NUL, we're done
        jne processLoop                 ; If it's not, loop again
        ret

main endp

end start
```

Here's a sample input and output:

Input: `HE`

Output: `DEA`

`D` and `A` are correct, but `E` is incorrect and printed in the same pass as `D`.

Will someone who isn't currently at wit's end please try to figure out what is going on here?

Comment: `movzx` gets the 32bit word! not a 8bit ASCII value. You have to use the `bl` 8bit register to point character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembler assumes that your `movzx` is supposed to convert 16-bit data to 32-bit since you haven't specified a size for the source data in the instruction.

Add a `byte ptr` specifier:

```
; Move a byte from [inputtxt+esi] to eax, zero-extended
movzx eax, byte ptr inputtxt[esi]
```

Comment: Yes!  That's brilliant.  I can't believe that I didn't realize that several hours ago.  I didn't realize that I had to specify the source data size.  Anyway, thank you very much.